# Max of a table into a column of a view

Tags: sql-server, view, sum

I'm trying to figure it out how to put a column of max of another table into a view table!
so here is my tables:

TblProprtyDetails

```
id    Property_id    amount     situation
 1         1           152         true
 2         1           545         false
 3         2            5          false
 4         2           87          true
```

TblExperties

```
id    PropertyDetails_id    ExpertiesDate     ExpertiesPrice
 1             1             2015-10-01             54
 2             1             2015-11-15             546
 3             2             2016-01-05             6895
 4             2             2016-08-01             654
```

now I want to put Max of ExpertiesDate and sum of amount into a view in this structure:

```
id    Property_id    amount     situation    LastExpertiesDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
id ,Property_id,amount,situation,max(ExpertiesDate) as lastexpertisedate
from
TblProprtyDetails t1
join
TblExperties t2
on t1.id=t2.id
group by
id ,Property_id,amount,situation
```

You also can use cross apply

```
select
    id ,Property_id,amount,situation,b.*
    from
    TblProprtyDetails t1
cross apply
(
select max(ExpertiesDate) as lastexpertisedate from table t2 where 
t1.id=t2.id) b
```

Comment: wow you r fast!
but it's wrong! it return all rows from TblProprtyDetails instead of return just one calculated row